# C# .net Sort Generica list on multiple values using CompareTo

Tags: c#, list, sorting, generics

I think I'm close on this, but not sure how/what to return from the CompareTo method.

My class has the following 3 properties that I want to sort on (which on has the highest value of three)
    public class Score{
        int Score1
        int Score2
        int Score3
    }

```
List<Scores> scores = new List<Scores>();
scores.Add(new Score{ Score1 = 50, Score2 = 40, Score3 = 30});
scores.Add(new Score{ Score1 = 30, Score2 = 60, Score3 = 50});
scores.Add(new Score{ Score1 = 20, Score2 = 90, Score3 = 100});
```

What I'm looking for is to sort making the 3rd row first since 100 is the highest number of any row. Row2 would be second since 60 is the next highest value of the remaining 2 rows. Then Row1 last.

Not sure of what to return?

```
    virtual public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is BaseAttack)
        {
            var compareObj = (BaseAttack)obj;
            if (compareObj.Score1 > compareObj.Score2 && compareObj.Score1 > compareObj.Score3)
            {
               return this.a.CompareTo(compareObj.a);
            }
            else if (compareObj.Score2 > compareObj.Score1 && compareObj.Score2 > compareObj.Score3)
            {
                return this.a.CompareTo(compareObj.Score2);
            }
            else
            {
                return compareObj.Score3;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a MyObject ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: would you try to read someone else's question if he/she posted a code like above?

Comment: "which on has the highest value of three" - please describe this a little better?

Comment: Can you show us six sample objects with different values, and the results of comparing multiple combinations of them (so we can be clear what you are asking for)?

Answer (score -2):

CompareTo returns an integer - a relative difference between objects. For example if you compare 2 integers you can return A - B.

In your case you need to return 1 if obj > this and -1 otherwise. If objects are equal return 0.